# Is there a way to create a "variable" in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to write a bunch of queries in a few scripts, but I want the user to be able to input a few variables such as year, and then use those variables as parameters in the queries. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What kind of scripts? Will you be passing these variables to your scripts?

Comment: I mean the ".sql" Not sure if thats the proper terms, but I am writing my queries on 4 or 5 different ".sql" files to organize. I want to have a variable on one of them that allows me to call it from the rest of the queries

Comment: `call it from the rest of the queries` - no, won't work. SQL variable scope is limited to current batch. There are no "global variables" (in common understanding) in MSSQL. XY problem again...

Answer (score 0):

You can use declare statement:

```
declare @month int = 7
declare @year int =2018
```

and then use these in queries:

```
....where month=@month and year=@year
```

Comment: I tried this and executed "declare @year int = 2017" but got this error "Must declare the scalar variable "@year"."

Comment: Either you can do

`declare @month int
declare @year int
set @month = 7
set @year = 2018`

or 

`declare @month int = 7;
declare @year int = 2018;`

Comment: If you got the "Must declare the scalar variable @year" message then either you didn't declare the variable @year or you are highlighting specific code to run but not also highlighting the declare code before it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this if your script(s) are going to be executed within the same batch.  If your users are going to load these scripts straight into SSMS or use a command line client like SQLCMD to execute then each script file will execute in its own batch and you'll need to declare the variable and set the values in each of the script files.

Otherwise you'll need to write a program or a script in some other language in order to prompt the user for the input values.  Your program will need to know how to set the variable values in each of or script files and then execute them against a SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 0):

To make this clear: A variable that is declared using a `DECLARE`statement is only valid within the "batch" it is declared in. A "batch" is a "submission" of commands that SQL Server analyses and executes as a whole. This could be the entire content of one .sql file, if the variable was declared in a statement in the file and if you executed the file as a whole and... - attention - if the script did not contain a `GO`. This little word `GO` isn't a SQL command, but it is a command for script-capable programs like SSMS. The purpose of this command is to mark an "end of the batch". It tells the program to "submit" and afterwards start a new batch (start to collect statements up to the next `GO` or up to the end of the file).

The only way to use a variable in your scenario is to create a single script file containing all commands from your " 4 or 5 different files" and remove every `GO` (at least between declaration and usage of the variable(s)).

If you need a value that can be accessed across multiple batches (and files), you will have to store the value in a table and query the value (into a variable) in every batch that needs to access the value.